# relative clause using where

Tags: grammar

Q: Are these sentences grammatically correct?

(1) The company has opened a new factory, **where it is** to create many new jobs.

(2) The company has opened a new factory, **where to create** many new jobs.

Answer (score -1):

Neither one is correct.  Here are suggested corrections.

1. The company has opened a new factory where there will be many new jobs.
2. The company has opened a new factory with the effect of creating many new jobs.

Comment: The first sentence is correct. The company is to create many jobs at their new factory.

Comment: I can agree that it is technically correct, but I know no one who would say it.  It sounds stilted.  If the focus is on the creation of jobs as a goal, then I would, instead, say, "The company has opened a new factory and will create many new jobs."

Comment: If it's correct, but stilted, then you should say that in your answer, not that 1 is incorrect.

Comment: Why is (2) incorrect?